# Can the number of differential equations of an expression be more than one?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have an differential equation Mdx + Ndy=0, then will the solution obtained from it f(x,y) when operated as d(f(x,y)) give the equation same as the initial differential equation.

Comment: Yes, it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by definition 
$$
d(f(x,y))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
$$

and $f(x,y)$ is a solution of $Mdx+Ndx=0$ if $M=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $N=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Comment: then does it mean that every DE of form Mdx + Ndy=0 if has a solution then the DE is exact?

Comment: No. But if it is exact the solution has this form $ f(x,y)=C$ and $M=f_x$ and $N=f_y$

Comment: So if an unexact equation's (Mdx + Ndy=0) solution f(x,y) is operated as d(f(x,y)) then the resultant differential equation should not be same as the initial one..?